# DB2 SQL Truncate a column using the year function and count the years

Tags: sql, count, db2, truncate

I have the following table: years

```
data
----
2005-07-12-09.21.54.000000
2005-07-12-13.58.58.000000
2005-10-17-22.36.32.000000
2005-09-17-16.34.38.000000
2005-10-29-13.31.26.000000
2002-07-16-15.23.13.000000
```

and i want to truncate it, with the year function and count the years. So basically like this:

```
 year        count
------      -------
2005         5
2002         1
```

I have tried different things, but i can't still not make the count how it should be.

```
select year(date) as year, 
count(date) as count
from years
group by date;
```

This give me the following output:

```
 YEAR         COUNT
--------      ----------
   2000           1
   2005           1
   2005           1
   2005           1
   2005           1
   2005           1
```

Can someone, please try to help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Group by `year(date)`:

```
select year(date) as year, 
count(date) as count
from years
group by year(date);
```

Comment: I'm receiving following message: No authorized routine named "YEARS" of type "FUNCTION" having
compatible arguments was found. @TheImpaler

Comment: What's the column type of the column `date`?

Comment: I haven't created the table, it's just an assignment and I'm still learning how to work with it. I guess date data type. @TheImpaler